# dateTime with different format in data frame

Tags: r, datetime

I have imported some data into R, which looks like the following:

```
              dateTime  temp
1 10/25/2005 12:00:00  15.50
2  10/25/2005 1:00:00  15.49
3  10/25/2005 2:00:00  15.52
4  10/25/2005 3:00:00  15.50
5  10/25/2005 4:00:00  15.50
6  10/25/2005 5:00:00  15.46
```

where the class of the dateTime column of the data.frame is factor and the second column is numeric.

I try to convert the dateTime into POSIXct format as follows:

```
dat[,1] <- as.POSIXct(dat[,1])
```

but receive the error

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

which I think is to do with the dateTime varying in the format that hour is presented e.g. 12, 1, 2 etc and not 12, 01, 02.

How can I change this to POSIXct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the format:

```
datetime <- factor("10/25/2005 12:00:00")

as.POSIXct(datetime)
#Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
#  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2005-10-25 12:00:00 CEST"
```

Note: I advise you to always specify a time zone explicitly when creating datetime variables. Otherwise, you could get into trouble with daylight saving time.

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
#[1] "2005-10-25 12:00:00 GMT"
```